# Time/hours syntax in JavaScript - how to do times that aren't on the hour

Tags: javascript, syntax

I'm using jQuery to show a different message depending on whether the business I work for is open or not. Since the business only opens at 9.30, I need to be able to write this into the jQuery but so far I've only been able to google things that specify times on the hour.

```
var thehours = new Date().getHours();
var themessage;
var open = ('nu open');
var gesloten = ('nu gesloten');

if (thehours >= 9.30 && thehours < 18) {
    themessage = open; 

} else if (thehours >= 18 && thehours < 24) {
    themessage = gesloten;

} else if (thehours >= 0 && thehours < 9.30) {
    themessage = gesloten;
}

$('.bericht').append(themessage);


var thehours1 = new Date().getHours();
var themessage1;
var open1 = ('09.30 - 18.00');
var gesloten1 = ('18.00 - 09.30');

if (thehours1 >= 9.30 && thehours1 < 18) {
    themessage1 = open1; 

} else if (thehours1 >= 18 && thehours1 < 24) {
    themessage1 = gesloten1;

} else if (thehours1 >= 0 && thehours1 < 9.30) {
    themessage1 = gesloten1;
}


$('.bericht1').append(themessage1);
```

These are two different messages that show either 'now open/now closed' and either the opening or closing times.

It works but only seems to show that's we're open between 10.00 and 18.00, not 9.30 and 18.00, so I wonder if the syntax on 9.30 is wrong.

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with jQuery, it is a question about JS syntax only.

Comment: ...but it is about javascript ;)

Comment: Sorry, my fault! :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick look at the [docs for `getHours`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours) would tell you that it returns the

> ... **integer number**, between 0 and 23, representing the hour for the given date according to local time.

So using `9.30` will never work (and if it did, you're using decimal numbers to represent that time - wouldn't it be `9.5`?!)

So you need hours *and* minutes:

```js
var date = new Date();
var hrs = date.getHours();
var mins = date.getMinutes();

if((hrs==9 && mins>30) || hrs >=10){
   console.log("Its past 930am")
}
```

Putting this together with the rest of your logic gives:

```js
function areWeOpen(){
  var date = new Date();
  var hrs = date.getHours();
  var mins = date.getMinutes();

  if(((hrs==9 && mins>30) || hrs >=10) && hrs<18){
     return true;
  }
  return false;
}

console.log( areWeOpen() ? "We are open" : "We are closed");
```

Simple!

Answer (score 1):

`9.30` is a floating-point number (i.e. 9 and 3 tenths), not hours and minutes in your code.
Since `getHours()` returns integer number of full hours, your code will act similar to:

```
if (thehours1 >= 10 && thehours1 < 18) {
    themessage1 = open1; 

} else if (thehours1 >= 18 && thehours1 < 24) {
    themessage1 = gesloten1;

} else if (thehours1 >= 0 && thehours1 < 9) {
    themessage1 = gesloten1;
}
```

which will return unexpected results for time 09:00 - 10:00.

You need to manually check hours and minutes.
Something like this:

```
var thehours = new Date().getHours();
var theminutes = new Date().getMinutes();
var themessage;
var open = ('nu open');
var gesloten = ('nu gesloten');

if (thehours === 9 && theminutes >= 30) { // 09:30 - 10:00 open
    themessage = open;
} else if (thehours >= 10 && thehours < 18) { // 10:00 - 18:00 open
    themessage = open;     
} else { // when we are not open - we are closed :)
    themessage = gesloten;
}

$('.bericht').append(themessage);
```

You don't need to create conditions for non-working hours, you can just find working hours, and use `else` for non-working.

As alternative, you can use some sort of "minute of day" term since it is easier to compare them:

```
function getMinuteOfDay(hour, minute)
{
    return hour * 60 + minute;
}

var now = new Date();
var nowMinuteOfDay = getMinuteOfDay(now.getHours(), now.getMinutes());

var isOpen = nowMinuteOfDay >= getMinuteOfDay(9, 30) && nowMinuteOfDay <= getMinuteOfDay(18, 00);
themessage1 = isOpen ? open1 : gesloten1;
```

Comment: Thank you all! It all makes sense now :D